# Delete tag 14.04.1

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [14.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04.1) seems useless, as there is already a 14.04 tag, and the questions involving the tag do not seem to be related to 14.04.1 but could be migrated to 14.04.

Comment: I deleted the tag two days ago... I really hate all `\d.\d` based tags. Just blacklist them all!

Comment: @Braiam wow you edit fast.. This post isn't relevant anymore as Braiam did a sweeping edit.

Comment: Hold your breath, it can appear in the next 24 hours if you don't keep at it.

Comment: @NoTime Users over 2k rep can edit without going through an approval queue, and users over 10k can edit tags inline without clicking the `edit` button in the question. More incentive for gaining rep, eh =)?

Comment: @AlaaAli note that despite the fact that I can do that, I didn't since most of those post required their titles to be fixed, comments to be added and down/close votes to be casted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I was able to evade the slash by a hairs breath and remove the tag just before the script ran. 24 hours have passed and the tag has not re-appeared. So, mission accomplished.

I would like [that this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11815/169736) gets implemented...