# Make numeric only/composed of just numbers tags that should only be created by moderators

Tags: feature-request, tags

Everyone knows I hate with burning passion version specific tags. The reasons are explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6enPm.png) and [elsewhere](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3102/41104), but that's not what I'm going to ask about.

Today, [I again removed the](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11813/16973) [14.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04.1) for second occasion. Keeping this kind of tags, that [literally](http://xkcd.com/725/) breeds like rabbit, is not an easy task and is just **a massive waste of my time**, which I could use for something more productive.

But hey, is not just that we don't teach them the correct use of the tags, but we also encourage their creation and application on posts that is only [incidental the version of Ubuntu OP was using](https://askubuntu.com/q/512184/169736) and frankly will not help them to get their question being answered, which gives place to [the most bizarre tag combinations](https://askubuntu.com/posts/513608/revisions) to occur, without doubt, OP can't hope to get their question answered, and I'm getting tired of this.

So, there's no doubt, this tags just hurts the site and should be only people with the supposed highest knowledge about how to use the different features of the site should be able to create them.

There are three alternatives, which aren't quite opposite, except for the last one:

1. Moderators are the only able to create tags that match the following regex: `/\d+(\.\d+)+/g`.
2. High reputation users (think 10k) or moderators are the only able to add tags matching `/\d+(\.\d+)+/g` to any question.
3. Only moderators are able to apply tags matching `/\d+(\.\d+)+/g` to questions.

Comment: s/literally/figuratively

Comment: Can such feature be applied to one SE site, but not others? This might be problematic to other sites, example: [magento.se]

Comment: @Dan according to Shog, is a per-site configuration.

Comment: just FYI @bjb568, I'm Cueball...