# Is Ubuntu 14.09 a thing? Should we have 14.09 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513967/is-ubuntu-touch-a-separate-distribution-or-the-same-one-14-04) about Ubuntu Touch, I found that there's apparently going to be a 14.09 release of it:

[Ubuntu 14.09 RTM, daily-preinstalled](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09/daily-preinstalled/)

Should we have a separate `14.09` tag for it?

Comment: Read this http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11815/169736. As this seems to be the current atmosphere regarding "version tags". I know you are talking about more "major" releases, but with such a large tag it may be best if it is under admin control (so everyone doesn't make version tags)

Answer (score 4):

No.  We shoudn't be fielding bug reports from an RTM.